# file_put_contents Cakephp error + Fatal error: Allowed memory size

Tags: cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-2.0, memory-size

In my website i am able to open almost all the link without any error. 
but when try to open this link :
http://scp.com/sh/admin/cities/add 
this show me this error :
 Warning (2): file_put_contents(/var/www/shcopy/sh/app/tmp/logs/error.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [CORE/Cake/Log/Engine/FileLog.php, line 87] Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in /var/www/shcopy/sh/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php on line 212

i checked my php.ini file the memory_limit is -1. 
Still i m getting this error.

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the memory usage of that link? Are you looking for a reason why the memory_limit = -1 does limit the memory usage anyway? Or do you want solutions to reduce the memory usage?

Comment: I am searching a solution why ini_set('memory_limit', '-1') in not working in my project and how to make my code work.

Answer (score 1):

Just increase your memory limit in php.ini/.htaccess/ini_set

Put the following line in AppController.php file

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

Or put the following line in your .htaccess file and check

```
php_value memory_limit 1024M
```

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); and check whether its working or not.. But this is not the right way

Comment: problem in your localhost or in server.. If in server check whether you have permission to set memory limit in php runtime

Comment: Currently in my localhost. the project is not deployed on server yet.